# Bean Velocity Config from xml to java

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'd like convert xml bean with velocity to config java class

This is old xml config:

```
    <bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

And this is new java class config:

```
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        VelocityViewResolver viewResolver= new VelocityViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        viewResolver.setCache(true);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig()
    {
       VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig = new VelocityConfigurer();

      // ???????????

       return velocityConfig;
    }
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`VelocityConfig` extends `VelocityEngineFactory`, so you can use the method [`setResourceLoaderPath`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory.html#setResourceLoaderPath(java.lang.String)):

```
velocityConfig.setResourceLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/View/");
```